# Bot Framework Bad Gateway for Double Quoted messages

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am having a very weird issue, I have a Chat Bot which is surfaced using a HTML page using DirectLine. But now **whenever I post a message with DOUBLE QUOTES in it, it just gives me a 502 Bad Gateway error**.

---

**JS CODE:**

```
BotChat.App({
            bot: bot,
            locale: params['locale'],
            resize: 'detect',
            speechOptions: speechOptions,
            user: user,
            botConnection: botConnection
        }, document.getElementById('BotChatGoesHere'));
```

---

**Chat Message:**
[image]

---

**Developer Console Error:**
[image]

---

**DEVELOPER CONSOLE NETWORK LOG:**[image]
I have been working with Bot Framework for quite sometime now, but this is the first time I am facing something like this.

Regards,

Hari

Comment: yes thanks, updated the answer.

Comment: Can you look at the network tab of your navigator and add in your question the content of this 502 message?

Comment: Hi Hari! Is this only occuring with double quoted messages? Can you post the dev console results of both a 'normal' message and a double quoted one?

Comment: Hey all, yes I am currently only facing this issue with double quotes. Also I have also updated the question to include, NETWORK Trace from Developer Console.

Comment: Hi Hari! I was able to semi-reproduce this (Mine doesn't 502, but gives me a strange response ("hi" => You said âhi€). Looking deeper into this.

Answer (score 0):

This has come up recently and is specific to the webchat and Directline channels. According to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1102) bug on Github,

> The smart quotes conversion are done by Markdown-It.
>
> https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it#init-with-presets-and-options
>
> By default, all message without textFormat will assume to be
>   "markdown". If you send activity of

```
{ type: 'message', textFormat: 'plain', text: '"What\'s up?"' }
```

> the message will be plain text and not go thru Markdown-It. Quotes will not turn into smart quotes.